# How can I replace every ID instance in a javascript Object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace every instance of the "id" with a random unique ID value.

Is there a way to replace all of them at once?

**My code:**

```
var theobject = [
    {
    "id":"lol",
    "milk":[
            {
                "id":"lol",
                "waffle":[
                        {
                            "id":"lol",
                            "eggo":[]
                        }
                    ]
            },
            {
                "id":"lol",
                "cookies":[]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
    "id":"lol",
    "donut":[
            {
                "id":"lol",
                "cheeto":[]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, A simple recursive solution which will update all the id:

```js
var theobject =[{"id":"lol","milk":[{"id":"lol","waffle":[{"id":"lol","eggo":[]}]},{"id":"lol","cookies":[]}]},{"id":"lol","donut":[{"id":"lol","cheeto":[]}]}];

function updateId(arr){
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length;i++){
     Object.keys(arr[i]).forEach((key)=>{
        if(arr[i][key].constructor.toString().indexOf("Array") > -1)
           updateId(arr[i][key]);
     });
      if(arr[i].id)
        arr[i].id = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8);
  }
}
updateId(theobject);
console.log(theobject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ramda` to help with modifying the object, and `cuid` to generate the unique ids:

```
const cuid = require('cuid')
const { evolve, map } = require('ramda')

const replaceIds = obj =>
  evolve({
    id: cuid,
    children: map(replaceIds)
  }, obj)

map(replaceIds, theobject) // usage
```

Outputs:

```
[
  {
    "id": "cji6e7qbf000cppatumn9nf6c",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "cji6e7qbf000dppatymupdw5r",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "cji6e7qbf000eppatbn3v7qlt",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "cji6e7qbf000fppat2ermw8jn",
        "children": []
    }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "cji6e7qbf000gppatuxiv0bsh",
    "children": [
    {
      "id": "cji6e7qbf000hppatx3em7n0e",
      "children": []
    }]
  }
]
```

**Note:**  This answers your questions as originally typed.  If the `children` props vary, but are all known, you can modify like this:

```
const replaceIds = obj =>
  evolve({
    id:      cuid,
    cheeto:  map(replaceIds),
    cookies: map(replaceIds),
    donut:   map(replaceIds),
    eggo:    map(replaceIds),
    milk:    map(replaceIds),
    waffle:  map(replaceIds),
  }, obj)
```

If they vary and are not known, then you'll need to try another method.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach = **recursive** solution. No libraries necessary.

Assuming you know for a fact that each object will have the **key's** `id` & `children` The below will work as posted.

Otherwise, if the key's may not exist on the object, then nesting each mutation scope inside "if" braces will be required.

```
const makeId = (objArray) => {
  return objArray.map((obj, i) => {
    obj.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1234567890);   // Just making a simple ID.  Typically use "uuid" or some other ID libarary generator.

    if (obj.children.length) obj.children =  makeId(obj.children);

    return obj;
  });
}

makeId(theobject);
```

**NOTE** 
This solution uses ES6.  If you need assistance setting up your app/algo for ES6 using Babel, check out an article I wrote [here](https://medium.com/@tobiahrex/es6-class-static-props-in-react-7b7480381e06) that will walk you through it.